# Portable ways to daily grind & powder/ paste 8-9 overnight soaked & peeled Almonds while traveling?

Tags: grinding, almonds, nut-butters

Portable ways to daily grind & powder/ paste 8-9 overnight soaked & peeled Almonds while traveling?

**Portable/ Light while Traveling:**

- May lack access to large food processor/ mixer/ grinder & will consider ideas/ methods using:

  - Manual/ Hand drive device/ or crucible/ vessel/ tool?
  - Automated & mechanized Small/ portable dual voltage 110/240 V device(s)

**Lacking food processing expertise:**

- I'm a young male who lacks the knowledge/ wisdom from my mother's decades of kitchen expertise & experience; and tool set / utilities

  - I will ask her as well, but hope wider pool can give some diverse answers

**Purpose:**

- This is for a herbal/ traditional medicinal home made recipe
- Needs to be done freshly every morning after overnight soaking

  - So easy, fast, time efficient will be crucial
- Overnight Soaked & Peeled Almonds consistency differs from dry almond/ or almond powder

  - It may or may not become a butter

**PS: First question on Cooking SE, so please be kind :) and don't negative me.**

Read this already: [How do I grind almonds for making marzipan?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/64886/how-do-i-grind-almonds-for-making-marzipan)

Comment: please explain why the other question doesn't work for you. Is it because your almonds are soaked, because you're traveling, or for some other reason?

Comment: @KateGregory - I think, I outlined it pretty clearly. 1. I'll be traveling so wont have a food processor/ most kitchen tools people have access to. Portable hacks are key. 2. Cant pre-do it as it needs to be freshly done every morning - portable + time efficient 3. Additionally, I don't know for sure, but DRY vs WET/ STICKY items act differently. 

I made sure to get these outlined constraints across clearly so that people get where I am coming from.

Comment: It's possible that a [manual coffee grinder](http://www.letsgrindsomecoffee.com/top-10-the-best-manual-coffee-grinder/) might work.  I don't know for sure that the almonds will fit through the process, if it will work with wet almonds, nor how easy it would be to clean, which is why I'm not posting this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use a small mortar and pestle, so you're not dependent on electric outlets, batteries or such. With this small amount, the required manual effort is very low, and you can use a very small mortar and pestle, so you can pack light. Also, you can soak the almonds in the mortar itself. And it is also possible to add other ingredients directly to the mortar after the pressing is done.

You will end up with a paste rather than ground almond flour, but I don't think you can get almond flour with soaked almonds in a food processor or a mill either.

Comment: Thank you for this advise. If at all I was to look for an "automated" option, is there something small that could help?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a battery operated pepper or coffee grinder? That must exist I would guess. The only issue might be you will be using soaked wet almonds so you will need a powerful motor.